# I'm receiving the wrong integers. instead of 7777 I'm supposed to get 0189

Tags: java, encryption

```
import java.util.*;    
public class LNFI_LNFI_program2 {    
static int globnum;    
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);    
 public static void main(String[] args) {    
  int globnum2 = globnum;    
  getnum();    
  encrypt(globnum2);      
 }

 // encrypt methods    
 public static int encrypt(int num)    
 {    
  num = globnum;    
   int firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit,  temp;      
   firstDigit = num / 1000 % 10;    
         secondDigit = num / 100 % 10;    
         thirdDigit = num / 10 % 10;    
         fourthDigit = num % 10;      
         firstDigit = (firstDigit + 7) % 10;    
         secondDigit = (secondDigit + 7) % 10;    
         thirdDigit = (thirdDigit + 7) %10;
         fourthDigit = (fourthDigit + 7) % 10;      
         temp = firstDigit;    
         firstDigit = thirdDigit;    
         thirdDigit = temp;      
         temp = secondDigit;    
         secondDigit = fourthDigit;    
         fourthDigit = temp;             
         System.out.printf("the encrypted number is %d%d%d%d\n",    
                 firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);             
   return num;    
 }     

 // getnum    
 public static int getnum()    
    {    
      int numentered;          
      System.out.println("Please enter a number");    
      numentered = console.nextInt();          
      return numentered;    
    }    
}
```

This is the return value, i receive

> Please enter a number
>   1234
>   the encrypted number is 7777

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the number passed to your `encrypt` method :

`num = globnum;`

`globnum` is 0 by default.

Of course, even if you didn't overwrite it, you are passing that same 0 to your `encrypt` method.

You never use the output of your `getnum()` method.

Therefore 0 is encrypted to 7777.

Change you main to :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {       
     encrypt(getnum());      
 }
```

and remove the first line of `encrypt`.